# How to attribute polygon with names of polylines it contains?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, geoprocessing

I have a set of polyline shapefiles and a polygon shapefile. The task is to split the polylines by the polygon border and write the names of polyline objects located within the polygon to the attribute table of the polygon shapefile. It's clear to me how to split lines by a polygon; **the problem is how to get the names and add them to the attributes of the polygon shapefile**.

Is there any way to do it in ArcGIS (ArcView license)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Spatial Join](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000000q000000.htm) is the geoprocessing tool for which you are looking.  The difficult situation you may encounter is when you have more than one polyline feature overlaying a single polygon feature.  The other parameters, including join operation, join type, and field mapping let you control exactly how the join is performed.